# Installing from network share, having issues with passing credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a GUI tool built with powershell that helps the setup of new PC's. I'm trying to add the ability for the user to install software from a domain network share by putting the path to the setup file into a text box. When they click "Run" it goes to that path and runs the setup.

I've got it to work as long as I have access to that share, however I'd like to include credentials into the `Start-Process` command. As of right now it says bad username or password whenever I try it.

The domain, user, and pass variables come from another part of the tool that joins the PC to the domain. That would happen first before the network install is started. The first two lines work fine for the domain joining, but don't work for the network install.

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "$pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $domain\$user,$pass

Start-Process -FilePath "$netinstall1" -Credential $creds -wait
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @user2460798, that seemed to fix the credentials issue. Here's what I'm running into now...

```
 New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\servername\folder -Credential $creds
 Start-Process -FilePath "$netinstall1" -Wait
```

`$netinstall1` is the full UNC path that the user will be putting in the text box, `\\servername\folder\setup.exe` in this case.

How do I strip out the `\setup.exe` or whatever the last part of the path will be so I can map the drive to `\\servername\folder` beforehand. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the problem is that `$creds` are used both to login into the file share and to start the process. In my case, anyway, the file share  doesn't have the same credentials as the local Windows machine. Even when I use a drive letter I still have the problem. Since running from a file share with a drive letter does work for you, it seems like you should break this into two steps: 1) map the drive 2) run the installer. You can use `new-psdrive` to map the drive. You can use the output from `get-psdrive` to find an available drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
 $path = Split-Path -Path $netinstall1 -Parent
 new-psdrive -name K -psprovider FileSystem -root "$path" -credential $creds
 Start-Process -FilePath "$netinstall1" -wait
```

Thanks!